# Sharing file via API in microsoft.sharepoint.online.csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to generate a anonymous view link for 12k files on my SharePoint Online. I use microsoft.sharepoint.online.csom. On an Internet I found a method ctx.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument but it doesn't appear in my case. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument is a PnP Extension method to generate anonymous links.

It wraps the `UpdateDocumentSharingInfo` method of DocumentSharingManager and generates the Anon links.

You dont need to necessarily use PnP to generate anon links.

You can directly use the OOTB CSOM methods of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing.DocumentSharingManager` class and generate links as below:

```
var users = new List<string>() { "user1@domain.com", "user2@domain.com" };

var userRoles = new List<UserRoleAssignment>();
foreach (var user in users)
{
    UserRoleAssignment role = new UserRoleAssignment();
    role.UserId = user;
    role.Role = Role.View; //Role.Edit
    userRoles.Add(role);
}

string absoluteFileUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Documents/Document.docx";
DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo(context, absoluteFileUrl, userRoles, true, true, true, "Your document", true, true);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

You just need to add the following using statement:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Sharing;
```

Reference - [DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt143107.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Does exist user like "All" or "Public"?

Comment: sorry didn't get you ? can you be more clear ? This will share the links with the users you have mentioned.

Comment: Think he thinks about just sharing with Anyone, People in "company" etc

Answer (score 0):

That method is part of the PNP client framework.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.externalsharingextensions.createanonymouslinkfordocument?view=sharepointpnpcoreonline-2.18.1709.0

You will need to reference the OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll to use it. 
( https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP )